# How to load type-2 JDBC driver by registerDriver( ) method?

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, driver

I am trying to load Type-2(Native API) driver by `registerDriver();` method. But it says OracleDataSource cannot be converted to Driver.

```
 import java.sql.DriverManager;
    import java.sql.SQLException;

    import java.util.Enumeration;
    public class Driver2_Load2 
    {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException
        {
            oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource d = new oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource();
            DriverManager.registerDriver(d);

            Enumeration e = DriverManager.getDrivers();
            if(e.hasMoreElements())
            {
                System.out.println(e.nextElement());
            }
        }
}
```

Then I tried type casting :-

```
oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource d = new oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource();
DriverManager.registerDriver((Driver) d);
```

But it throws an Exception, `java.lang.ClassCastException: oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource cannot be cast to java.sql.Driver`

To run:-

```
set classpath=;D:\ORACLE-11g\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\jdbc\lib\ojdbc6.jar;
javac Driver2_Load2.java
java Driver2_Load2
```

Answer (score 2):

Loading the type 2 driver is not different than loading the type 4 driver because the actual driver class is always the same. The type 2 driver also needs a complete Oracle client installed (in contrast to the type 4 driver, which only needs the .jar file)

With any modern Java and driver version there is no need to call `registerDriver()` or `class.forName()`. All you need to do is to provide a connection URL using the `oci` protocol rather than the `thin` protocol.

[As documented in the manual](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/JJDBC/urls.htm#BEICDECB) an OCI connection is established using the driver protocol `oci`: `jdbc:oracle:oci:...`

So to create an OCI connection, you need to specify that in the URL:

```
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:oci:@//localhost:1521/orcl", "hr", "hr");
```

But you **have** to have the Oracle client including all needed DLLs installed and reachable for your JVM, but there is no need to call `registerDriver()` (or `Class.forName()`)

---

Regarding your code: `oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource` is - as the class name indicates - an implementation of `javax.sql.DataSource` it's not a `javax.sql.Driver`.

`registerDriver()` expects the class name of a `java.sql.Driver`, not of a `DataSource`.

The Oracle driver class is `oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver`.

---

Unrelated, but: why to do you think you need the OCI driver in the first place? [Oracle recommends](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/JJDBC/overvw.htm#JJDBC28033) to use the thin driver, unless you have very specific requirements, e.g. you need "Transparent Application Failover" in a RAC environment.

Comment: Even stronger, application code should **never** call `DriverManager.registerDriver`; it is only to be called by the JDBC driver itself (ignoring certain edge-cases of non-registering drivers).

Answer (score -1):

See https://docs.oracle.com/cd/F49540_01/DOC/java.815/a64685/basic1.htm, the syntax is:

```
DriverManager.registerDriver (new oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver());
```

Comment: This is for type-2 driver or type-4 driver?

Comment: Application code should never call `DriverManager.registerDriver`. That documentation (which btw is for Oracle 8.1, so not very recent) is blatantly wrong.